# How to sort an array using regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, sorting

I have an array which looks like this

```
arr = ["#0abc", "#2egf", "#0pol kol", "#1loa", "#2ko pol"]
```

As you can see, each element in the array has `#n` associated with it where `n` is any number between `0-9`. Now based on the `n`, I want to sort by array in ascending order such that the final output looks like this

```
[ '#0abc', '#0pol kol', '#1loa', '#2egf', '#2ko pol' ]
```

So this is what I do

```
rankWordMap = {}
finalArr = []
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    rank = entry.charAt(1)
    if(rankWordMap[rank]) {
        rankWordMap[rank].push(entry);
    }
    else {
        rankWordMap[rank] = [entry];
    }

})

for (var key in rankWordMap) {
    if (rankWordMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        finalArr.push(...rankWordMap[key])
    }
}

console.log(finalArr)
```

I get the expected output but as you can see, it's pretty inefficient. Besides I could have hundreds of elements sometimes where I would like to quickly sort it rather than doing it this way.

Is there any shorter way to implement this? I am specifically looking for a regex solution but other solutions are fine too.

Comment: `arr.sort( (a,b) => a.match(/#(\d+)/)[1] - b.match(/#(\d+)/)[1] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex, just sort based on the integer value of the second character in each entry:

```js
arr = ["#0abc", "#2egf", "#0pol kol", "#1loa", "#2ko pol"];

arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a[1]) - parseInt(b[1]));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: wow this is nice non regex solution.

Comment: @SouvikRay I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the first coming digits and take this value for sorting.

```js
var
    getValue = string => string.match(/\d+/),
    array = ["#0abc", "#2egf", "#0pol kol", "#1loa", "#2ko pol"];

array.sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));

console.log(array);
```